# Delay binding of second-level type parameter

Tags: java, generics, higher-kinded-types

This is a bit of a contrived reproducing case, but bear with me.

Suppose you want to create an adder interface for classes capable of adding items to different types of lists with the following behavior:

```
// Can add items to any type of array list.
Adder<ArrayList> arrayListAdder = ...;
// Ok. Right list type and item types match.
arrayListAdder.add(new ArrayList<String>(), "test");
// Ok. Right list type and item types match.
arrayListAdder.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(), 3);
// Compile error. Item types do not match.
arrayListAdder.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(), "test");
// Compile error. Wrong list type although item types match.
arrayListAdder.add(new LinkedList<String>(), "test");
```

In other words, I want the interface to say:

> An adder for an specific list type has a method 'add'. This method takes two arguments. 
>   The first is a list of this specific type with items of type T. 
>   The second argument is an item of type T. The method adds the item to the list.

I tried with different solutions along the lines of:

```
interface Adder<L extends List<?>> {
    <T> void add(L<T> list, T t);
}
```

But the expression `L<T>` is illegal in its context. The error message I get is "Type 'L' does not have type parameters".

I cannot find a way of leaving the type parameter of the list open until the definition of the add method. Is there any way of specifying this interface, or does that require higher-order generics or something else which Java doesn't have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface Adder<T, L extends List<T>> {
    void add(L list, T t);
}

class ArrayListAdder implements Adder<String, ArrayList<String>> {
    @Override
    public void add(ArrayList<String> list, String t) {
        list.add(t);
    }
}
```

I don't think binding `T` is possible at `add` definition time, since `T` must be known in order to declare `L` having a type parameter (it must be given in either bound or unbound form).

I believe you are looking for the equivalent of this C++0x code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <template <typename _ElementT, typename _AllocatorT> class CollectionT>
struct Adder {
    template <typename ElementT, typename AllocatorT>
    void add(CollectionT<ElementT,  AllocatorT> &collection, ElementT element);
};

struct VectorAdder : public Adder<std::vector> {
    template <typename ElementT, typename _Alloc>
    void add(std::vector<ElementT,  _Alloc> &vector, ElementT element) {
        vector.push_back(element);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vi;
    vi.push_back(1);

    std::vector<double> vd;
    vd.push_back(1.1);

    VectorAdder va;
    va.add(vi, 2); // instantiates VectorAdder::add<int, ...>
    va.add(vd, 2.2);  // instantiates VectorAdder::add<double, ...>

    for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x << ' '; });
    for_each(vd.begin(), vd.end(), [](double x) { std::cout << x << ' '; });
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm pretty sure that's not possible in Java.

Comment: Oh... It seems you do not wish to have the add method generic and List parameter unbound in an implementor of Adder? So my code won't work? Or does it solve your problem?

Comment: I believe the question stated that the type parameter of the list wants to be unassigned until the method is called, which means it can't be put in the interface. Unfortunately, Java Generics do not have this kind of functionality.

Comment: @Irfy: Spot on. Although I agree that this seems reasonable, it unfortunately does not solve my specific problem.

Comment: Maybe there is an alternative approach to solving the problem. What exactly are you trying to solve? In other words, why does that approach seem to be necessary?

Comment: @Irfy: I'm trying to define generic methods dealing with wrapped types. I have several wrapper types, so I can have Wrapped1<int> and Wrapped2<int>. I have different wrappers and unwrappers for 1 and 2. These should share an interface so that the chained wrapping logic is unaware of the specific wrapper type. I run into the problem that WrapperType1 must have a merhod that takes Wrapped1<T> for all T and implement Wrapper<Wrapped1>. At least that is the gist.

Comment: I can work around it with some casts, but I was surprised that it didn't work. This is the first time I encountered this problem.

Comment: I don't honestly think I'll be able to help you, but I'm kind of curious -- could you [post](https://gist.github.com/) the version of the code with casts?

Comment: There, one more approach in a new answer from me.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort. I will try and see if I can apply your second apprpach to my original problem somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Java Generics do not support the functionality you are looking for. The closest you can get is to require a List in the method, and not use type L. Such as:

```
interface Adder
{
    <T> void add(List<T> list, T t);
}
```

This isn't what you are looking for though, so the next closest thing would be to move your List declaration into the method body, however this is also incorrect:

```
interface Adder
{
    <T, L extends List<T>> void add(List<T> list, T t);
}
```

The problem is you are attempting to assign a generic type to an arbitrary type (L), while L may not be genericized, despite forcing `L extends List<?>`. There is no good way to force the check at compile time or at run time of the list type.

Comment: Thank you for a nice straightforward answer (and the first). I'm going to accept Irfy's answer, though, due to all the effort he put into it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you mean but

```
public interface Adder<T, L extends List<T>> {

    void add(L list, T t);
}
```

sounds like an option

Comment: Duplicate of the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

This will compile but it does not enforce your rules.

```
interface Adder<L extends List<?>> {
    <T> void add(L list, T t);
}
```

You can do this to enforce your rules

```
interface  Adder<L extends List<T>, T> {
    void add(L list, T t);
}

class foo implements Adder<List<Integer>, Integer> {
public void add(List<Integer> list, Integer t) {
...
```

Comment: This interface requires making an adder for a specific container and item type. I wanted an adder for a specific container type, but for all item types.

Answer (score 1):

After many rewrites, does this do what you want?

```
interface Adder<L extends Collection<S>, S> {
    public S add(L c, S s);
}

class AdderImpl <L extends Collection<S>, S> implements Adder<L, S> {
    public S add(L c, S s) {
        c.add(s);
        return s;
    }
}


public void test() {
    Adder<List<String>, String> listAdder = new AdderImpl<List<String>, String>();
    Adder<Set<String>, String> setAdder = new AdderImpl<Set<String>, String>();

    listAdder.add(new ArrayList<String>(), "Hello");
    // setAdder.add(new ArrayList<String>(), "Hello");  Complier error - can't use List on SetAdder
    setAdder.add(new HashSet<String>(), "Hello");
}
```

Comment: I believe he wants to parametrize with the unbound collection type when implementing `Adder`, and bind the collection type when invoking `add`. The opposite of what you did there. I think.

Comment: This one doesn't enforce container type.

Answer (score 1):

to shorten my answer i gave an example using a class:

```
class Adder<T, L extends List<T>> {
    void add(L list, T t) { /* your logic */}
    void test() {
         new Adder<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>().add(new ArrayList<Integer>(), new Integer(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this do

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
interface Adder<K> {
    void add(List<K> l, K k1);
};

class IntegerListAdder implements Adder<Integer> {
    public void add(List<Integer> l, Integer i) {
        l.add(i);
    }
}

class StringListAdder implements Adder<String> {
    public void add(List<String> l, String i) {
        l.add(i);
    }
}

public class AdderTest {
    public static void main(String... argv) {
        IntegerListAdder ila = new IntegerListAdder();
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ila.add(l,1);
        ila.add(l,2);
        System.out.println(l);
        StringListAdder sla = new StringListAdder();
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        sla.add(s,"One");
        sla.add(s,"Two");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs fine.

Comment: He wants `ArrayListAdder`, `SomeOtherCollectionAdder`, etc. and then be able to add any type to an appropriate list, with one `add` function per class. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered *pulling your collection parameter down*? That is, to the method level. So that you do not have separate adders with a common interface, but just one, global adder that handles all cases. Consider this:

```
class Adder {
    public <T, W extends Wrapped<T>> void add(ArrayList<W> list, W w) {
        System.out.println("list.add " + w);
        w.commonWrappedMethod();
        list.add(w);
    }

    public <T, W extends Wrapped<T>> void add(HashSet<W> set, W w) {
        System.out.println("set.add " + w);
        w.commonWrappedMethod();
        set.add(w);
    }

    // For all other collections
    public <T, W extends Wrapped<T>> void add(Collection<W> col, W w) {
        System.out.println("col.add " + w);
        w.commonWrappedMethod();
        col.add(w);
    }
}
```

The `Adder` is then invoked like this:

```
ArrayList<Wrapped1<Integer>> w1il = new ArrayList<Wrapped1<Integer>>();
HashSet<Wrapped1<String>> w1ss = new HashSet<Wrapped1<String>>();
Vector<Wrapped2<String>> w2sv = new Vector<Wrapped2<String>>();

Adder adder = new Adder();

adder.add(w1il, new Wrapped1<Integer>(1));
adder.add(w1ss, new Wrapped1<String>("six"));
adder.add(w2sv, new Wrapped2<String>("twelve"));
```

You would no longer need (or be able to employ meaningfully, in fact) an interface for the adder, you would just pass around/use the single object. Or even better, you would make the methods static and use the class as a utility class, or make the class a singleton and always refer to the one instance.

Full example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/1856690).

Comment: Possible approach. You overdid it slightly, since I never had both wrappers and lists. But still a viable approach. I would like to have pluggable adders, though, which this approach prevents.